# Is there difference between different ways of creating an object that contains other objects and is passed to a function to be added to a vector

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, initialization, std

If we have a clas that contain vector of objects of other class

```
   class BigClass
    {
    private:
    vector<ClassName> vec;
    //more code
    public:
    void AddItem(const ClassName& i) {vec.push_back(i);}
    //more code
    };
```

And ths class also contain objects of other classes(structs, as they are simple). Which contain yet another objects.

```
class ClassName
{
private:
StructName obj;
//more code
public:
ClassName(const StructName &s) : obj(s) {}
ClassName(double x,
 double y,
 int i,
 const &OtherStruct o1,
 const &OtherStruct o2) 
 : obj({x, y, i, o1, o2}) {}
};

struct StructName 
{
 double x;
 double y;
 int i;
 OtherStruct o1;
 OtherStruct o2;
};

struct OtherStruct
{
  int x;
  int y;
  int z;
};
```

Is there any difference/benefits/downsides between different options of calling AddItem? Imagine we already have variables `double x, double y, int i, const &OtherStruct o1, const &OtherStruct o2`

```
AddItem({x, y, i, o1, o2}); //1
AddItem(ClassName{x, y, i, o1, o2}); //2
AddItem(ClassName(x, y, i, o1, o2)); //3
AddItem(StructName{x, y, i, o1, o2}); //4
AddItem(ClassName{StructName{x, y, i, o1, o2}}); //5
AddItem(ClassName(StructName{x, y, i, o1, o2})); //6
```

Comment: It is in your best interests to make sure the code example makes sense. If you provide gibberish examples you run the odds of people completely ignoring the question in favour of trying to fix all of the problems in the example.

Comment: indeed it is a little odd that you posted the classes in reverse order.

Answer (score 3):

No.  All of those are just different syntaxes for constructing a `ClassName`, but they're all fundamentally the same thing.  Then that `ClassName` gets passed to `AddItem`, and how it was constructed makes no difference at all. And the implementation of this will allocate more room in the vector, and then copy the object into itself.

However:

```
template<class...Us>
void AddItem(Us&&...vs) { vec.emplace_back(std::forward<Us>(vs)...);}
```

This works subtly different, this passes along the parameters as-is to the vector, which will allocate more room, and then construct the `ClassName` directly inside of itself, which may or may not save your cpu the work of making two copies of your `ClassName`. (Important note: The optimizer may already be doing this with the code you have, I don't know.)

This complexity probably isn't worth it, since `ClassName` appears trivially copiable.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to work. Maybe `(vec.emplace_back(std::forward<Us>(vs)), ...);`?